# Paginating with lambdas in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement pagination with lambdas, but it seems it is not possible without the good-old-do-while cycle:

```kotlin
        val list = mutableListOf<String>()
        var pageIndex = 0
        do {
            val items = paginate<ListResponse>(pageIndex++)
            list += items
        } while (items.isNotEmpty())
        return list
```

I would like to write it like:

```kotlin
        var pageIndex = 0
        return collectElements {
            paginate<ListResponse>(pageIndex++)
        } until { it.isNotEmpty() }.flatten()
```

Are there any collection utils which would be helpful without having to implement it?

Comment: What are your concerns with the do-while implementation? It looks perfectly fine and will likely be easier to understand for someone who isn't familiar with less frequently used functional operators.

Comment: I just don't find it kotlin-enough :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val list = generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }
    .map { paginate<ListResponse>(it) }
    .takeWhile { it.isNotEmpty() }
    .flatten()
    .toList()
```

Comment: this looks promising! how does this guarantee it doesn't generate infinite list at the generateSequence?

Comment: `generateSequence` returns [Sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html#sequence) (It is similar to Java Stream). Multi-step processing of sequences is executed lazily when possible. It will work like this: generate 1 -> map paginate(1) -> check if isNotEmpty -> flatten -> generate 2 and etc. `generateSequence` will stop generating values after the predicate in `takeWhile` returns `false`